# How to add an informative popup over a given text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some options of book titles and I would like to add on mouse hover over each of them a popup with some meaningful description of the book. The popup should appear above the respective book title and cover it. I'm not sure how to handle this, perhaps jQuery could help. I can't imagine a solution without Javascript, using only CSS.

The HTML looks like this (it can be changed, if necessary):

```
<tr><td>
<input type="radio" value="book1" name="download"> Book 1 <br>
<input type="radio" value="book2" name="download"> Book 2 <br>
<input type="radio" value="book2" name="download"> Book 3 <br>
</td></tr>
```

Over each of Book 1, Book 2, and Book 3, there should appear an info popup (with stuff like number of pages, summary etc) on mouse hover.

Comment: with only html you can do <span  title="5 pages..."><input type="radio" value="book1" name="download"> Book 1</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many jQuery tooltip plugins that can help you achieve that. For the plugins to work, usually you just have to add a "title" attribute to your HTML.

Have a look at some of them http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/07/jquery-tooltip-plugin.html and choose the one with the UI matching your need.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to adapt this pure CSS method that uses the contents of a data attribute as the tooltip contents:
http://www.impressivewebs.com/pure-css-tool-tips/

Works in IE8+

Answer (score 1):

http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/ would be the fastest way to implement probably

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you the [tipsy jquery plugin](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/).  A modified version is also availabe with [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips).